# How to integrate OCL constraints to a model created with Eclipse Sirius?

Tags: ocl, eclipse-sirius

Its difficult to give more details as I haven't even found a clue in OBEO Designer Community to model OCL constraints.

Anyone has a idea how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add Validation rules with a constraint expressed in AQL -- Acceleo Query Language (a flavor of OCL) directly in the .odesign file.

See the[corresponding part of the tutorial](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Sirius/Tutorials/AdvancedTutorial#Validation_Rules).